# coordinate transformation of operators

Tags: coordinate-systems

I recently came across a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6O6iZug6e6Y) on transformation electromagnetism (yes this is physics) and some of the math equations that was postulated did not have any references. I have been searching the web to find references but with out any luck. As my mathematical understanding is limited to math used in physics I simply do not really know how to formulate my search correctly.

**missing reference number 1**

In the youtube video it was postulated that a function $\vec{E}$ in $R^3$ transformed as:

$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=A^T\vec{E'}(\vec{r}')$

under coordinate transformation where ' indicates the transformed coordinate system and A is the jacobian matrix for the given coordinate transformation.
I believe this is simply the invers function theorem?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

**missing reference number 2**

This is my real missing reference and it is postulated at 8:52 in the video.

A linear operator $F$ is transformed under coordinate transformation as:

$F'(\vec{r}')= \frac{AF(\vec{r})A^T}{\text{det}A}$.

Again A is the jacobian for the given coordinate transformation and the ' indecates the transformed coordinate system.

I apologise for my sloopy physics-formulation of the question.

Comment: $A$ is supposed to be a $3 \times 3$ matrix, i.e. a linear operator $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and $E,F$ are functions $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. finally, if $f(\vec{r}) = A \vec{r}$ (i.e. $f$ is a linear operator) then $A$ is also the Jacobian of $f$ at any point $\vec{r}$ (the derivatives and hence the Jacobian of a linear operator being constant)

Comment: what is the difference between an operator and a function ?

Comment: and for "number 2"  I don't get what is $F$ and what is $A F(r) A^T$

Comment: In the video I believe a functions is meant to be well a function that maps points from $R^3$ to $R^3$. Operators acts on functions for instance gradient, divergence or curl is meant as operators.

Comment: ok  but if $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and $F(r)$ a $3 \times 1$ matrix (a vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$) then $F(r) A^T$ means nothing, nor $(A  F(r)) A^T$. possibly $F(r)$ could be a $3 \times 3$ matrix, but in that case the jacobian of $F_2(r) = \frac{A F(r) A^T}{\det A}$ is complicated and is not $A$

Comment: For instance in 13:58 in the video they apply the equation to the curl operator. $\nabla'\times$= $\frac{A(\nabla\times)A^T}{\text{det}A}$. I know this notation is really wrong.

Comment: and I said bullshit, the Jacobian of $F(r) =  A r$ is $A (1,1,1)^T$ of course (i.e. the video is...)

Comment: this is correct :" the operator $F \to \nabla_2 \times F$ is defined by $\nabla_2 \times F(r) = A (\nabla \times (A^T F(r)))$"

Comment: How about the division with $\text{det}A$?

Comment: it is just the multiplication by a constant $C = 1/\det A$

Comment: Ok so is it correct understood that we have to divide with $1/\det A$ if the coordinate systems aren't orthonormal? For transformation between orthonormal coordinate systems det A would allways be 1 right?